# Order List of Objects by List inside object c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of Objects (`obj1`) and inside each object I have another list of objects like shown below:

**`List <Obj1> obj1`**

**`Obj1`**

- `string Name`
- `List <Obj2> obj2`

**`Obj2`**

- `string Name`
- `int Id`

I want to order list of `obj1` by order marked by list of `obj2` `Id`s.

First element in list of `obj2` defines the order of `obj1` list, if they are the same the second one defines order, and so on until end of list of `obj2`.

Example data:

- "Test" : {("A", 2), ("B", 3)}
- "Test2" : {(("C", 1), ("D", 2)}
- "Test3" : {(("A", 2), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)}

Result data:

- "Test2" : {(("C", 1), ("D", 2)}
- "Test3" : {(("A", 2), ("B", 2), ("C",3)}
- "Test" : {("A", 2), ("B", 3)}

Comment: Are you really using `List<object>`? Because that really complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution will implement the `IComparable` interface with the `int CompareTo(object obj)` method for `Obj2` and `Obj1`.
`Obj2` has to be compared by it's `Id` and `Obj1` will be compared by the `List<Obj2>`.
With that you can call `Sort()` on a list like: `List<Obj1>`.

Here on [ideone is my full working live example with complete code](https://ideone.com/DIbsCR).

The following are the code snippets needed and described above:

```
class Obj2 : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Obj2 other = obj as Obj2;
        return Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    }
}

class Obj1 : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Obj2> Objects { get; set; }

    // ...

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Obj1 other = obj as Obj1;
        /* loop until one list ends */
        for (int idx = 0; idx < Objects.Count && idx < other.Objects.Count; ++idx)
        {
            int comparison = Objects[idx].Id.CompareTo(other.Objects[idx].Id);
            /* if not equal return */
            if (comparison != 0)
            {
                return comparison;
            }
        }
        /* if they were equal until now use count to compare */
        return Objects.Count - other.Objects.Count;
    }
}
```

**Resulting Output:**

```
"Test2" : { ("C", 1) ("D", 2) }
"Test3" : { ("A", 2) ("B", 2) ("C", 3) }
"Test" : { ("A", 2) ("B", 3) }
```